# Dereferencing a list reference in hash element

Tags: perl

Can someone finish this for me and explain what you did?

```
my %hash;

#$hash{list_ref}=[1,2,3];
#my @array=@{$hash{list_ref}};

$hash{list_ref}=\[1,2,3];
my @array=???

print "Two is $array[1]";
```

Comment: Why do you want a reference to an array reference?

Comment: It actually has other code feeding it.  This is just the simplified version of the actual problem.

Comment: That's not a list reference, it's an array reference. Lists and arrays are different things in Perl.

Answer (score 6):

```
@array = @{${$hash{list_ref}}};
```

`(1,2,3)` is a list.

`[1,2,3]` is a reference to <strike>a list</strike> an array (*technically, there's no such thing in Perl as a reference to a list*).

`\[1,2,3]` is a reference to a reference to an array.

`$hash{list_ref}` is a reference to a reference to an array.

`${$hash{list_ref}}` is a reference to an array.

`@{${$hash{list_ref}}}` is an array.

Since a reference is considered a scalar, a reference to a reference is a scalar reference, and the scalar dereferencing operator `${...}` is used in the middle step.

Comment: You could even shorten it to `@${$hash{list_ref}}`, although that doesn't help clarity at all.

Comment: `[1,2,3]` returns a reference to an array. A reference to a list (`\(1,2,3)`) produces a list of references. Nothing alike.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pretty much already answered the question, but more generally, if you are ever confused about a data structure, use [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html). This will print out the structure of the mysterious blob of data, and help you parse it.

```
use strict;     #Always, always, always
use warnings;   #Always, always, always
use feature qw(say);  #Nicer than 'print'

use Data::Dumper;     #Calling in the big guns!

my $data_something = \[1,2,3];

say Dumper $data_something;
say Dumper ${ $data_something };
```

Let's see what it prints out...

```
$ test.pl

$VAR1 = \[
            1,
            2,
            3
          ];

$VAR1 = [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ];
```

From the first dump, it appears that `$data_something` is a plain scalar reference to an array reference. That lead me to add the second `Dumper` after I ran the program the first time. That showed me that `${ $data_something }` is now a reference to an array.

I can now access that array like this:

```
use strict;     #Always, always, always
use warnings;   #Always, always, always
use feature qw(say);  #Nicer than 'print'

use Data::Dumper;     #Calling in the big guns!

my $data_something = \[1,2,3];

# Double dereference
my @array = @{ ${ $data_something } };  #Could be written as @$$data_something

for my $element (@array) {
    say "Element is $element";
}
```

And now...

```
$ test.pl
Element is 1
Element is 2
Element is 3
```

It looks like you meant:

```
my $hash{list_ref} = [1,2,3];
```

and not:

```
$hash{list_ref} = \[1,2,3];
```

That latter one got you an scalar reference of a array reference which really doesn't do you all that much good except add confusion to the situation.

Then, all you had to do to refer to a particular element is `$hash{list_ref}->[0]`. This is just a shortcut for `${ $hash{list_ref} }[0]`. It's easier to read and understand.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my %hash;
$hash{list_ref} = [1, 2, 3];

foreach my $element (0..2) {
    say "Element is " . $hash{list_ref}->[$element];
}
```

And...

```
$ test.pl
Element is 1
Element is 2
Element is 3
```

So, next time you are confused about what a particular data structure looks like (and it happens to the best of us. Well... not the *best of us*, It happens to me), use `Data::Dumper`.

Answer (score 0):

```
my %hash;

#$hash{list_ref}=[1,2,3];

#Putting the list in square brackets makes it a reference so you don't need '\'
$hash{list_ref}=[1,2,3];

#If you want to use a '\' to make a reference it is done like this:
# $something = \(1,2,3); # A reference to a list
#
#   or (as I did above)... 
#
# $something = [1,2,3]; # Returns a list reference 
#
# They are the same (for all intent and purpose)


print "Two is $hash{list_ref}->[1]\n";


# To make it completely referenced do this:
#
# $hash = {}; 
# $hash->{list_ref} = [1,2,3];
#
# print $hash->{list_ref}[1] . "\n";
```

To get at the array (as an array or list) do this:

```
my @array = @{ $hash{list_ref} }
```

Comment: Yes, as stated above, this a simplified version of the actual problem, so I can't do as you want.  If you look at my commented code above, you will see that I already have included this solution.

Comment: Actually ... `\(1,2,3)` is NOT the same as `[1,2,3]`. `\(1,2,3)` gives `( \1, \2 , \3 )`. Try feeding it to `Data::Dumper`.

Comment: dgw is correct. I stand corrected. I hope there is no longer a Perl tribunal. I admit it: I was too lazy to go back to the book.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ EXPR ]
```

creates an anonymous array, assigns the value returned by EXPR to it, and returns a reference to it. That means it's virtually the same as

```
do { my @anon = ( EXPR ); \@anon }
```

That means that

```
\[ EXPR ]
```

is virtually the same as

```
do { my @anon = ( EXPR ); \\@anon }
```

It's not something one normally sees.

---

Put differently,

`1,2,3` returns a list of three elements (in list context).

`(1,2,3)` same as previous. Parens simply affect precedence.

`[1,2,3]` returns a reference to an array containing three elements.

`\[1,2,3]` returns a reference to a reference to an array containing three elements.

---

In practice:

```
my @data = (1,2,3);
print @data;
```

```
my $data = [1,2,3];      $hash{list_ref} = [1,2,3];
print @{ $data };        print @{ $hash{list_ref} };
```

```
my $data = \[1,2,3];     $hash{list_ref} = \[1,2,3];
print @{ ${ $data } };   print @{ ${ $hash{list_ref} } };
```